# How to convert dynamic property to string

Tags: c#, json, string, datetime

I have some dynamic object, `data`:

```json
{
    ...
    "start": "2022-09-24T04:04:00Z",
    ...
}
```

and I want to get the string value `"2022-09-24T04:04:00Z"` into a variable. Whenever I try casting, or printing or `data.ToString` etc, the string is automatically formatted to `"24/09/2022 4:04:00 AM"`.

How can I convert this dynamic property to a string without changing its format?

It looks like it's being interpreted as a datetime, and then calling `DateTime.ToString` on it, which must convert the format.

The dynamic comes from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` btw.

Comment: "It looks like it's being interpreted as a datetime, and then calling `DateTime.ToString` on it" Yeah I think that's what happening here too. Do you want it to stay as a string?

Comment: I do eventually want it as a DateTime, but I want it deserialised as a string. In my use case, it makes more sense to deserialise into a string and then convert into a DateTime depending on other conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off DateTime handling via `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = "{\"start\": \"2022-09-24T04:04:00Z\"}";
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json, settings);
    Console.WriteLine(result["start"]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, rather than trying to convert back to the original string, just don’t serialise it in the first place. Cheers